# How to form probability density function using Kronecker symbol?

Tags: probability-distributions, kronecker-symbol

The question gives the PDF using two cases of random variable X. The solution begins with the PDF of X as stated below. I don't understand how they got to that point. I tried to take delta_0 to be 1 if x=0 and 0 if else. And delta_t to be 1 if x=t and 0 if else. But this doesn't fit at all with the computing of the Expected Value.

[image: Question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of $\delta_t$ is correct. It is fine with the computation of the expectation.
$$\mathbb E(X)=\sum_{x} x\times f(x)$$
$$=\sum_{x} x\mathbb P(X=x)$$
where sum is over the values taken by random variable $X$.
$$\Longrightarrow \mathbb E(X)=0\times \Big(1-\frac{1}{a}\Big)+a\times \frac{1}{a}=1$$

Comment: But isn't 0 also a value that X can take? So why are we only summing over values that are non 0?

Comment: Additionally, shouldn't it be $$ 1\times \frac{1}{a} $$ ? Because delta_t becomes 1 for every value of a that is greater or equal to 1.

Comment: We **are** taking $0$ under consideration, observe the first sum in the expression for expectation.

Comment: Also, $\delta_t(x) = 1$ only at $x=t$, and is $0$ otherwise. So, $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}\delta_t(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ and the written term is correct.

Comment: The first sum is $0\times$ that follows from the fact that we are taking sum over $x\times probability$. That has nothing to do with kronecker delta, the $x$ is from outside $f$.

Comment: I am SO SORRY! I kept skipping a step. You are absolutely right. Thank you so much for the help!